# NodeJS error: throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs

I have created a simple React + node-postgres + expressJS + PostgreSQL DB webapp.

It just has two inputs and a button. When I press the button the values are stored in my DB.

The ExpressJS server is running with nodemon. The app works fine if the server runs. When I enter the first value and then press the button, everything gets stored correctly - after a short period of time the nodemon server crashes with the errors shown below.

```
C:\node tutorial\reactPSQLexpress\backend>nodemon server.js
[nodemon] 1.19.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Listening to PORT: 7777
{ country_name: 'test', continent_name: 'test' }
Data INSERT succesfull
events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end
    at writeAfterEnd (_stream_writable.js:243:12)
    at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:291:5)
    at Connection.end (C:\node tutorial\reactPSQLexpress\backend\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:339:22)
    at Client.end (C:\node tutorial\reactPSQLexpress\backend\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:525:21)
    at Pool._remove (C:\node tutorial\reactPSQLexpress\backend\node_modules\pg-pool\index.js:161:12)
    at Timeout.setTimeout (C:\node tutorial\reactPSQLexpress\backend\node_modules\pg-pool\index.js:44:12)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)


Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Client.idleListener (C:\node tutorial\reactPSQLexpress\backend\node_modules\pg-pool\index.js:78:10)
    at Client.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Connection.connectedErrorHandler (C:\node tutorial\reactPSQLexpress\backend\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:182:10)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Socket.reportStreamError (C:\node tutorial\reactPSQLexpress\backend\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:72:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at writeAfterEnd (_stream_writable.js:245:10)
    at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:291:5)
    at Connection.end (C:\node tutorial\reactPSQLexpress\backend\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:339:22)
    at Client.end (C:\node tutorial\reactPSQLexpress\backend\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:525:21)

[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I already killed all node servers and startet everything again but after inserting one value the same happens.

```
taskkill /f /im node.exe
```

kill command worked fine - but proplem still exists.

EDIT: Serverside code:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  })
);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});

app.post("/api/new-country", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  let country_name = req.body.country_name;
  let continent_name = req.body.continent_name;

  pool.connect((err, db, done) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).send(err)
    } else {

      db.query("INSERT INTO country (country_name, continent) VALUES($1, $2)",[country_name, continent_name], (err, table) =>{
    //   db.query("SELECT * from country", (err, table) => {
        done();
        if (err) {
          return res.status(400).send(err) 
        } else {
        //   console.log(table.rows);
          console.log("Data INSERT succesfull");
          db.end();
          res.status(201).send({message: "Data inserted!"})
        }
      });
    }
  }); 
});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening to PORT: ${PORT}`));
```

I moved the db.end behind res.status(201) ... but it didnt help.

Comment: `write after end` means the express server is writing back a response for a request which has already ended. Could you paste your server side code

Comment: show us your code

Comment: I edited the question - I just left out my pool settings and the require imports from the file. Thanks for your responses.

Comment: why is the res.status(201) inside the query cb, move it to the endpoint scope

Comment: what is inside done() function ?

Comment: @Roy.B Do you mean I have to move it before the last ` }); app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening to PORT: ${PORT}`));  `  ? I tried but it didnt help.

Comment: @yesIamFaded put it in the bottom of the else of pool.connect, after the db.query(...)

Comment: @AnshulJindal + Roy.B  -- I put the function down in the pool.connect scope and I removed the done(); call because it was actually doing nothing. The server doesnt crash now and everything seems to work. Thanks guys

Comment: @Roy.B Hi Roy - do you know how to fix : _________   Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client ________ this error? I read few things and it says it can be caused by multiple callbacks or by the next(); method. It happends on my DELETE operation. Ty in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this same error, and it turns out I had a typo in my .env file.
I wrote

```
PORT=2000; #instead of PORT=2000
```

Comment: I also listened to my port a little differently: console.log(`Listening to PORT: ${process.env.PORT}`);